# FiddlerCore in VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, fiddler

Does anybody know how to use FiddlerCore in vb.net?  I've worked with some C# to vb.net tools but they can never convert it to something that works.  Code examples (or even full projects) or site references would be nice.

Thanks if you can!

-Hopeless.

**--EDIT--**

I have the following code that I have adapted (from a wonderful post below).  This doesn't seem to be working, however.

```
Private Sub StartProxy()

    If Not FiddlerApplication.IsSystemProxy Then
        AddHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeResponseHandler
        AddHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeRequestHandler
    End If

    FiddlerApplication.Startup(80, True, False, False)

End Sub

Private Sub FiddlerBeforeRequestHandler(ByVal tSession As Session)
    RichTextBox1.Text &= "REQUEST:  " & tSession.fullUrl & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub FiddlerBeforeResponseHandler(ByVal tSession As Session)
    RichTextBox1.Text &= "RESPONSE:  " & tSession.fullUrl & vbCrLf
End Sub



Private Sub StopProxy()

    Try
        RemoveHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeResponseHandler
        RemoveHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeRequestHandler
        FiddlerApplication.Shutdown()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    StartProxy()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    StopProxy()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried [Telerik's converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)? They have an interface to convert multiple files and I have had good luck with their converter. You'll end up having to manually convert/fix some portions with any converter.

Comment: This didn't work, does anybody have any actual examples of such a thing (using FiddlerCore in vb.net)?

Comment: So I assume that nobody has any possible suggestions.

Comment: You need to be more specific... What exactly isn't working? Note that among other problems your code has background threads writing to the UI. You shouldn't do that, you need to Invoke on the main thread to avoid breaking cross-thread rules.

Comment: The code I provided in the edit is code that was given to me by a person answering below.  The code doesn't do anything.

Comment: EricLaw is talking about your updating of the RTB.  Since the event is being fired from a non-UI thread, updating the RTB without marshalling the update to the UI thread violates cross-thread rules.

Comment: Something along the lines of:
Private Delegate Sub UpdateRTBDelegate(byval tMessage as string)
Private Sub UpdateRTB(byval tMessage as string)
if RTB.InvokeRequired Then
me.invoke(new UpdateRTBDelegate(addressof UpdateRTB), New String() {tMessage}
Exit Sub
End If
RTB.Text &= tMessage
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# should be faily simple to convert.  But.. ah well.. here's a little sample:

```
    Private Sub StartProxy()

        If Not FiddlerApplication.IsSystemProxy Then
            AddHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeResponseHandler
            AddHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeRequestHandler
        End If

        FiddlerApplication.Startup(8090, True, False, False)

    End Sub

Private Sub FiddlerBeforeRequestHandler(ByVal tSession As Session)
  ' Code to process the request before it is passed along to the next server in the request chain.
End Sub

Private Sub FiddlerBeforeResponseHandler(ByVal tSession As Session)
  ' Code to process the response before passing along to the next client in the response chain (typically the browser)
End Sub



Private Sub StopProxy()

        Try
            RemoveHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeResponseHandler
            RemoveHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeRequestHandler
            FiddlerApplication.Shutdown()
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm still having problems, however.  I've edited my op to reflect the code I am now dealing with.  Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry DalexL, I've no time right now to debug, and nothing pops out at me.  Drop me a comment in a couple days if you're still having trouble.